AUTOSAR UML Class Diagram Arrow Notation
As shown in the snippet from AUTOSAR UML Class Diagram, please let me know which document describes the meaning of 3 types of Arrow Connectors 1/2/3


No offense, but you mentioned in your question that this picture shows a UML diagram. Therefore, you should already be aware that  the semantics of the line ends is explained in the UML standard itself. The UML standard has no affiliation with AUTOSAR. What's your actual question and why did you tag the question as relevant for AUTOSAR?

I am unable to find any document which describes the meaning of those Arrow End Points. Some hints of the Documents which describes those Arrow End Point Symbols will be helpful.
That's all. Because I found those snippets in AUTOSAR Document, I thought somewhere in the AUTOSAR Spec it should be well documented about the nomenclature and associated meanings or at least refer to some relevant UML Standards. If you can provide me that will be useful for me to understand better.

So, your question would be more like "Can you provide the specification of UML graphical semantics? (for example the three highlighted elements in this example which happens to be AUTOSAR)"?

Since you are aware that this is UML, can you state the UML specification you are using and point out which parts are unclear to you and ideally why? I ask because I am with Uwe, in thinking that your question is a UML question, which you mistagged as AUTOSAR. If this IS somehow an AUTOSAR question then at least two users have misunderstood it.

However, let me point out that UML seems to be using UML to define itself, while not being very good at doing that bottom up (i.e. not first defining elements which it uses to define other elements....). So please try to see the helpful intention of my comments above.

What I can find in a short time is https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF chapters for "1" 11.5.5, figure 11.33; "2": 9.7.5, "3": 7.5.5, figure 7.12. These more accidentally than intetentionally are simple enough examples of using the three elements you point out to almost serve as introduction. I do not mean this to be an answer to your question. But if this looks like the kind of answer you hope for, then I think it means I understood your question. If not, please point out why not, which might help others (and me) to understand your question.

Funnily enough "OMG" is almost exactly what I thought during my first UML training.... most of the time... repeatedly... increasingly emotionally...

You Linked PDF with Section Numbers as well as Figure Numbers are the exact information I was looking for.
Really appreciate for all the relevant details.
